# Airflow Configuring AD/LDAP Admin Users And Regular Users

Tags: active-directory, ldap, airflow

I have Airflow successfully setup to work with my AD/LDAP when everyone is a superuser and data profiler. But now I want to define an admin group and a regular user group. I have the following settings,

**Working Config Where Everyone Is An Admin:**

```
# set a connection without encryption: uri = ldap://<your.ldap.server>:<port>
uri = ldap://123.456.789:123
user_filter = objectClass=*
# in case of Active Directory you would use: user_name_attr = sAMAccountName
user_name_attr = sAMAccountName
# group_member_attr should be set accordingly with *_filter
# eg :
#     group_member_attr = groupMembership
#     superuser_filter = groupMembership=CN=airflow-super-users...
group_member_attr = member
group_name_attr = CN
group_filter = objectclass=group
bind_user = CN=blah,OU=foo,DC=us,DC=bar,DC=com
bind_password = yahoo
basedn = DC=us,DC=bar,DC=com
# Set search_scope to one of them:  BASE, LEVEL , SUBTREE
# Set search_scope to SUBTREE if using Active Directory, and not specifying an Organizational Unit
search_scope = SUBTREE
```

**New Config With Specific Admin Group Set:**

```
# set a connection without encryption: uri = ldap://<your.ldap.server>:<port>
uri = ldap://123.456.789:123
user_filter = objectclass=*
# in case of Active Directory you would use: user_name_attr = sAMAccountName
user_name_attr = sAMAccountName
# group_member_attr should be set accordingly with *_filter
# eg :
#     group_member_attr = groupMembership
#     superuser_filter = groupMembership=CN=airflow-super-users...

superuser_filter = memberOf=CN=MyAdminGroupName,OU=foo,DC=us,DC=bar,DC=com
data_profiler_filter = memberOf=CN=MyAdminGroupName,OU=foo,DC=us,DC=bar,DC=com

group_member_attr = member
group_name_attr = CN
group_filter = objectclass=group
bind_user = CN=blah,OU=foo,DC=us,DC=bar,DC=com
bind_password = yahoo
basedn = DC=us,DC=bar,DC=com
# Set search_scope to one of them:  BASE, LEVEL , SUBTREE
# Set search_scope to SUBTREE if using Active Directory, and not specifying an Organizational Unit
search_scope = SUBTREE
```

*Resource: https://airflow.apache.org/security.html*

With this new configuration I am able to log into the Airflow UI but I'm no longer able to view the Admin tab. I am 100% sure I am a part of the admin group *MyAdminGroupName*. I'm also not sure where to put my regular user group name *MyRegularGroupName*.

**Can someone please guide me on how to configure my Admin group (*MyAdminGroupName*) and my regular user group (*MyRegularGroupName*)?**

Comment: I think this is closely dependend on your LDAP structure, which is not included in the question. It might be a good idea to give as much information as possible.

Comment: Did you find any answer to this ?

Comment: Still facing the same problem with 1.10.3, was this ever solved?

Answer (score 3):

I also struggled with setting up LDAP in Airflow.

First of: What is `group_filter = objectclass=group` in your config? I cannot find it specified in the docs or in the [`ldap_auth.py`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/auth/backends/ldap_auth.py).

Then, your `group_member_attr` is set to `member`, but in the filter queries you're using `memberOf`, so I guess that `memberOf` should be your `group_member_attr` (it usually is, if your using Active Directory).

Your `superuser_filter` and `data_profiler_filter` look good to me.
To whoever reads this: the filters are inserted into a string like this in the code: `(&(<FILTER_HERE>))`, so if you want to build a more sophisticated filter, take this into account.
E.g. I wanted to only give three users superuser rights (using environment variables for config):

```
AIRFLOW__LDAP__SUPERUSER_FILTER: "&(objectCategory=Person)(|(sAMAccountName=user1)(sAMAccountName=user2)(sAMAccountName=user3))(memberOf=CN=MyDepartment,OU=Departments,OU=UserGroup,DC=MyCompany,DC=local)"
```

Regarding your question about `MyRegularUserGroup`: I guess, you can specify the user filter to filter for persons in your regular user group and then specify the admin group for superuser and data profiler. But that would only work if the admin group is a subset of the regular user group.

Hope that helps.